# Shifting fit and its data on x axis

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
l={{46, 1714.29}, {47, 2857.14}, {48, 3714.29}, {49, 5428.57}, {50, 
  8928.57}, {51, 8928.57}, {52, 11571.4}, {53, 14571.4}, {54, 
  17785.7}, {55, 25000.}, {56, 29571.4}, {57, 34214.3}, {58, 
  39214.3}, {59, 44142.9}, {60, 49928.6}, {61, 55714.3}, {62, 
  62214.3}, {63, 69571.4}, {64, 76285.7}, {65, 76285.7}, {66, 
  93571.4}, {67, 104071.}, {68, 114000.}, {69, 121143.}, {70, 
  127786.}, {71, 137214.}, {72, 144929.}, {73, 153143.}, {74, 
  153143.}, {75, 167571.}, {76, 167571.}, {77, 178214.}, {78, 
  183071.}, {79, 186786.}, {80, 188643.}, {81, 191571.}, {82, 
  194786.}, {83, 197214.}, {84, 200214.}, {85, 202500.}, {86, 
  205071.}, {87, 207286.}, {88, 209357.}, {89, 211357.}, {90, 
  213286.}, {91, 214857.}, {92, 216000.}, {93, 217571.}, {94, 
  218286.}, {95, 218714.}, {96, 219643.}}
```

To find the normal distribution fit I do,

```
FindFit[l[[All, 2]], 
 a PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x], {a, \[Mu], \[Sigma]},
  x]
```

Then I plot them using:

```
Show[ListPlot[l[[All, 2]], PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[9.492714442567708`*^6 PDF[
    NormalDistribution[44.10417734334825`, 17.28548314618452`], 
    x], {x, 0, 200}]]
```

As you can see they are both starting on `0`. This is because I used `l[[All, 2]]`, I wonder how can I move data and the fit to start from `x=46` and onwards, to be consistent with `x` values of list `l`.

Comment: I'm curious as to the reason for not using the full dataset:  `sol = FindFit[l, 
  a PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x], {{a, 10^5}, {\[Mu], 
    40}, {\[Sigma], 20}}, x]` followed by `Show[ListPlot[l, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[a PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x] /. sol, {x, 0, 
   200}]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{minx, maxx} = MinMax@l[[All, 1]];
fit = FindFit[l[[All, 2]], a PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x], {a, μ, σ},   x];
```

Use the option [`DataRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) in `ListPlot` and shift the argument `x` in the first argument of `Plot` by `-minx`:

```
Show[ListPlot[l[[All, 2]], PlotStyle -> Red, DataRange -> {minx, maxx}],
  Plot[a PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x - minx] /. fit, {x, 0, 150}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it, this can be done using:

```
Show[ListPlot[l], 
 Plot[9.492714442567708`*^6 PDF[
     NormalDistribution[44.10417734334825`, 17.28548314618452`], 
     x], {x, 0, 200}] /. l_Line :> Translate[l, {46, 0}]]
```